# DropBox API/ListView?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, dropbox-api

I am implementing a file lister with Dropbox API. So I access the Dropbox home folder of the person, and I list and search for some files of that specific format, in this case, .epub.

I am targeting Android 4.4. So I was very surprised when running the application in the main thread, when I try to access the dropbox home Folder, I was getting a denied status. I found out it was the network error that has appeared many times, with Android 3.0. However if I try to do it asynchronously it fails.

I access and list all the folders, filters all the .epub files,and obtain the information of that file(*name*, *path*, and *modified date*). I store that data in an Entry format in a public variable in this thread.

However as it is done asynchronously, I have no idea when this information is obtained(it could be in the middle, or in the end of the main thread), so when the main thread asks for those values their content is empty. Anyway that this will work?
Should I use Dropbox Sync API? has anyone used Dropbox sync API and is it thread safe?

Comment: Please format your question in paragraphs. It's barely readable!

Comment: You should never use the main thread for networking. In fact, it's explicitly disallowed. Google provides constructs such as [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to accomplish exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Yes, in fact if I implement it in Asynctask it's asynchronous, so until the thread has finished the data won't be correctly set.If I am  getting 15 epub files from the dropbox folder asynchronously, how can I tell the main thread the results are available?

Comment: check out the documentation Josh linked to. onPostExecute is "invoked on the UI thread after the background computation finishes"